# toggleClass functionality using html field value

Tags: javascript, css, html

Right now I'm using toggleMonotoneMode to toggle a css class, but I'd like to add the ability to allow the user to select the color.

existing css:

```
.monotone [id^='_'] {
fill: #339933;
}
```

existing js:

```
var toggleMonotoneMode = function() {
  helpers.toggleClass(build, 'monotone');
};
```

new html5 functionality:

```
<input id="monotonecolor" type="color" value="#339933" />
```

half done javascript:

```
var monotoneSelect = document.getElementById('monotonecolor');

monotoneSelect.value = ?

monotoneSelect.addEventListener('click', function() { helpers.addClass(build, 'monotone') }, false);
```

edits:

Attempt1: doesn't work...

```
var toggleMonotoneMode = function() {
  monotoneSelect.value = build.style.fill;
};

monotoneSelect.addEventListener('click', function() { monotoneSelect.value = build.style.fill; }, false);
```

Attempt2: close...

```
var buildfill = document.querySelectorAll('build[id^="_"]')

var toggleMonotoneMode = function() {
  buildfill = monotoneSelect.value;
};
```

Attempt3: I realized a mistake I made

```
var buildfill = document.querySelectorAll('build[id^="_"]')

var toggleMonotoneMode = function() {
  buildfill.style.fill = monotoneSelect.value;
};

monotoneSelect.addEventListener('click', function() { buildfill.style.fill = monotoneSelect.value; }, false);
```

hmm... still not getting matches for [id^="_"] (returns undefined), but that is probably beyond the scope of this question.

how do I make this toggle though?

```
var toggleMonotoneMode = function() {
  buildfill.style.fill = monotoneSelect.value;
};
```

Comment: Why would the user not be able to select a color? It's a `<input type="color">` after all.

Comment: @Bergi, the only reason I would see is an incompatible browser...

Comment: I'm not sure how to attach `input.value` to `.monotone [id^='_']`. :/

Comment: Don't use a stylesheet, but an inline style. Just do `build.style.fill = input.value`

Comment: @Tyblitz I'm working on a polyfill for html5 color for incompatible browsers

Comment: @Bergi maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but that isn't working... see update in OP

Comment: [This might help](http://jsfiddle.net/563AC/)

Comment: I suggested the assignment to be the other way round? Also, probably when `click` is fired the new color isn't set yet (though I'm not sure how color-inputs are working)

Comment: ahh I got it working almost. It's going to .build, but it needs to go to `.build [id^='_']` sorry

Comment: [___Creating css dynamically___](http://www.webgeekly.com/tutorials/jquery/how-to-switch-css-files-on-the-fly-using-jquery/)

Comment: @Bhavik I don't need to change the stylesheet...